# Index starting from 0 but it should start from 1? ajax method is correct or not if it is than how to retrieve this parameter in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
function setdata() {
    alert('hello');
    var index = 1;
    $("tr").each(function(index, value) {
        var rowValues = new Array(); $(this).find('input').each(function() {
            rowValues.push($(this).val());
        })
        alert("row" + index + " : " + rowValues);
        //do something with rowValues
    })

    //var info = [];
    //$("tr").each(function(trIdx, element) {
    //   $("td.input").each(function(trId, element) {
    //     alert($element.text);
    //    info.push($element.text);
    //});
    // });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pdtentry.aspx/Done",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ id: '" + $info + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            alert('Yay! It worked!');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('Oh no :(');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

In the above code it show three rows `row 0`, `row 1` and `row3` but I have only two rows. Any ideas?

I think that index should start from 1 but don't know how to do that. Also a table heading `th` row is there in the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/7a8Uu/

can you please tell me that my ajax method is correct or not if it is than how to retrieve this parameter in c#

Comment: please create a jsfiddle. If you can. remember once you do $("tr") it takes all the row in the page may not be from same table. So make sue you do not have more than 1 table in the page.

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: $("tableid tr") also gives the same result so the problem may not be with the selector

Comment: Right off the bat, I see a problem with the 'data' property in the AJAX call. It is not valid JSON. Try: data: {"id": +

Comment: My phone messed up, I am on mobile now so I can't type much and lost connection in a tunnel. I was saying it needs to be proper JSON which looks like {"id":"value"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the scope of your function, you have a variable called 'index' whose value is 1. However, inside the `$.each` callback function, index is a *differetnt* variable from yours.  In fact, it doesn't matter what you call it, its value will be whatever value jQuery decides to pass in as the index, and jQuery always uses 0-indexing in the `$.each` callback. If you want your index variable to be 1-indexed instead of 0-index, you can simply increment the index passed into the callback by 1:

```
//Note I changed 'index' to 'i' to show you that it doesn't matter what you call it - it is its own independent variable because its scope is the callback function.
$("tr").each(function(i, value) {
    var oneIndexed = i + 1;  //Shifts to be 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed.
    var rowValues = new Array(); $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        rowValues.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert("row" + oneIndexed + " : " + rowValues);
    //do something with rowValues
});
```

Also, if you are seeing extra rows than you expect, it is probably due to your selector `$("tr")`. You want to have specific selectors. For example, if your rows you want to iterate over are inside a table with id 'myTable', use the selector `$("#myTable tr")` to avoid accidentally looping over rows elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: using the selector of type:$("#myTable tr") still extra row comes check the fiddle

Comment: If your table has an ID 'tr' and you are getting extra rows with that selector, then 100% guaranteed they are coming from that table

Comment: can you please tell me that my ajax method is correct or not if it is than how to retrieve this parameter in c#

Answer (score 1):

It *doesn't* work that way.

The callback doesn't care what previous variable `index` there was, or what it was set to. The callback introduces a *new* variable `index` (the parameter, which shadows `index` from the outer scope) and it is *always* 0-indexed in the jQuery collection.

If you wish to "offset" the value, then do it manually - but it has *no bearing* on the jQuery callback/result.

---

In addition, `$('tr')` will match *every* table row in the document; such a general selector can be very problematic.

Comment: can you please tell me that my ajax method is correct or not if it is than how to retrieve this parameter in c#